# Flutter provider assistance please

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, state-management, flutter-change-notifier

I am trying to pass my _myUnit.unit value from this custom widget to my screen that calls the widget to confirm what units a user has selected. Currently I am able to print the correct values when the Icons.loop is pressed but don't have access when I press calculate on my implementation screen. Any advice? I think I have to get rid of my ValueListenableBuilder and change to provider?

***Piece of widget to change units***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_form_builder/flutter_form_builder.dart';
import 'package:form_builder_validators/form_builder_validators.dart';

import 'my_unit.dart';

enum Units { unitImperial, unitMetric }
typedef OnSaved(value);

class TextFieldEntry extends StatefulWidget {
  TextFieldEntry(
      {required this.name, required this.onSaved, this.formCallBackFunction});

  final String name;
  final OnSaved onSaved;
  final Function? formCallBackFunction;

  final myDecorationField = InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'textFieldName',
    labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.pink),
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topRight: Radius.circular(0),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(0),
      ),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        width: 1,
        color: Colors.pink,
      ),
    ),
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topRight: Radius.circular(0),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(0),
      ),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.pink,
        width: 1,
      ),
    ),
  );

  @override
  State<TextFieldEntry> createState() => _TextFieldEntryState();
}

class _TextFieldEntryState extends State<TextFieldEntry> {
  var _validator;
  var _keyboard;
  var _myUnit;

  String unitSelected = 'unit Error';

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.name == 'height') {
      final heightValidate = FormBuilderValidators.compose([
        FormBuilderValidators.required(context),
        FormBuilderValidators.numeric(context),
        FormBuilderValidators.max(context, 200),
        FormBuilderValidators.min(context, 30)
      ]);

      _validator = heightValidate;
      _keyboard = TextInputType.number;
      _myUnit = MyUnit();
    } else if (widget.name == 'weight') {
      final weightValidate = FormBuilderValidators.compose([
        FormBuilderValidators.required(context),
        FormBuilderValidators.numeric(context),
        FormBuilderValidators.max(context, 450),
        FormBuilderValidators.min(context, 30)
      ]);

      _validator = weightValidate;
      _keyboard = TextInputType.number;
      _myUnit = MyUnit(imperial: 'lbs', metric: 'kg');


} else {
      _validator = null;
      _myUnit = null;
    }

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxWidth: 375,
                maxHeight: widget.name == 'Description' ? 100 : 50),


//- Textformfield code

            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: FormBuilderTextField(
                    name: widget.name,
                    maxLines: widget.name == 'Description' ? 5 : 1,
                    decoration: widget.myDecorationField.copyWith(
                        labelText: widget.name,
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary)),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary))),
                    onSaved: widget.onSaved,
                    validator: _validator,
                    keyboardType: _keyboard,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                      border: Border.all(
                          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                          width: _myUnit != null ? 2 : 0)),

//- Text for the unit changing button (i.e. inches)
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      if (_myUnit != null)
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: Center(
                            child: ValueListenableBuilder<Units>(
                                valueListenable: _myUnit,
                                builder: (context, unit, _) => AutoSizeText(
                                      _myUnit.unitType,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Theme.of(context)
                                              .colorScheme
                                              .onPrimary,
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                    )),
                          ),
                        ),
                     Builder(
                        builder: (context) {
                          void changeUnit() {
                            Units unit = _myUnit.unit;
                            _myUnit.unit != null
                                ? _myUnit.unit = unit == Units.unitImperial
                                    ? Units.unitMetric
                                    : Units.unitImperial
                                 : '';
                          }
                          void updateSelectedUnit() {
                            widget.selectedUnit = '${_myUnit.unitType}';
                            print(widget.selectedUnit);
                          }

                          if (widget.name == 'height' ||
                              widget.name == 'weight' 
                              ) {
                            return Container(
                              constraints:
                                  BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 50, maxWidth: 60),
                              child: TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  changeUnit();
                                  updateSelectedUnit();
                                },
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Icon(Icons.loop,
                                      size: 30,
                                      color: Theme.of(context)
                                          .colorScheme
                                          .onPrimary),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          } else {
                            return Container();
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 12,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

***MyUnit widget***

```
class MyUnit extends ValueNotifier<Units> {
  //You want to check when the enum Units change, so that will be your ValueNotifier
  final String _imperial;
  final String _metric;

  MyUnit(
      {Units unit = Units.unitImperial,
      String imperial = 'inches',
      String metric = 'cm'})
      : _imperial = imperial,
        _metric = metric,
        super(unit);

  String get unitType => value == Units.unitImperial
      ? _imperial
      : _metric; //The labels you define, just like unit1 and unit2 in TextFieldEntry
  Units get unit => value; //the enum value
  set unit(Units newUnit) =>
      value = newUnit; //when this change, it will rebuild the listeners
}
```

***Example implementation***

```
class Input {
  var title;
  var unit;

  Input({
    this.title,
    this.unit,
  });
}

class BMIDosing extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<BMIDosing> createState() => _BMIDosingState();
}

class _BMIDosingState extends State<BMIDosing> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();


List<Input> _traditionalList = [
    Input(
      title: 'height',
    ),
    Input(
      title: 'weight',
    ),
    Input(title: 'age'),];

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar(title: 'Traditional'),
      drawer: MainDrawer(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Container(
                constraints:
                    BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 475, maxWidth: 375), //Needed
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: _traditionalList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext inp, index) {
                      return _traditionalList[index].title ==
                                                      'height' ||
                                                  _traditionalList[index]
                                                          .title ==
                                                      'weight' ||
                                                  _traditionalList[index]
                                                          .title ==
                                                      'age'
                                              ? TextFieldEntry(
                                                  name: _traditionalList[index]
                                                      .title,
                                                  onSaved: (value) {
                                                    _traditionalList[index]
                                                        .title = value;
                                                  },
                                                );

 }),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Calculate'),
                onPressed: () {
                  // if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                  _formKey.currentState?.save();
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `ValueNotifier` from "screen" to "widget". "screen" has access to `value`, while "widget" sets new `value`.

Screen

```
class Screen extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueNotifier<int> _counter = ValueNotifier<int>(0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Child(_counter),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.calculate),
        onPressed: () => print(_counter.value),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Widget

```
class Child extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueNotifier<int> _counter;
    
  const Child(this._counter);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () => _counter.value += 1,
      child: const Icon(Icons.plus_one),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess that is my question. How do I go about getting a ValueNotifier from "Screen" to "Widget"?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me as my ValueNotifier is nested in myUnits widget vs the Textfield app where the button to change the units is located. I updated my code to show the entirety of the textformfield code and see if that adds any value.